# Xamarin.Forms Carousel Page Swipe Event Page Changing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm using the Carousel Page that ships with Xamarin Form (2.5.0) and would like to be able to detect when a page is about to change.

Each Page has some validation and if this fails I want to prevent the user from moving to the next page.  Currently the only event I can see is PageChanged and this is where I trigger the validation, however the user must swipe back to see the error message.

Is there a way to hook into the native swipe event?

The App is currently targeting iOS, however it will eventually need to support Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but maybe someone else might also ask, so here's an idea:
As you wrote, in

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
```

you could find out when a user swiped to the next page. Now if you do the validation for the previous page, you could go back to the previous page in case of error with

```
int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
this.CurrentPage = this.Children[index-1];
```

This does not prevent the user from leaving the page (as there is no 'OnSwipingStart' or else), but the user will see the error without having to move back manually.

If you are happy to use a different control than CarouselPage:
There is a [pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/853) to get [CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) into native Xamarin Forms. It has a Scrolled-Event which is triggered already on the first percent swiped so you could do your actions there.

Comment: Thanks for the response - this is more or less the solution I implemented.  It would be a better user experience if there were an event before the page changed...

Comment: I've updated my answer with link to CarouselView. I wasn't sure whether you are stuck to the CarouselPage or whether you want to have a look at a different control.

Comment: I’m not limited to just the CarouselPage - the CarouselView looks very interesting - will see how it works with my App!

Comment: The ItemSource property has been changed from an IList to IEnumerable which means ItemSource can't be set in XAML.  All my Views are currently defined using XAML they would need to be migrated to c#