# Detect Swipe Event of a Carousel View

Tags: c#, android, binding, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am developing in Xamarin Forms using a MVVM framework and I have an issue when using a Carousel View.

Within my Carousel, I have several different types of pages that can be displayed by using templates.

This part works correctly and I can see the different pages by swiping the view.

My problem is that on one of the pages in the view I need the data to be updated when the page loads so I need some way to detect the Swipe Event so that I can perform a check to see which page is currently loaded and then I can reload the data when the relevant page is shown.

I have bound a property to the SelectedIndex of the control hoping that when the index changes I can catch this in the Setter and then I can reload the data if it is the correct page.

This is where my issue occurs.

If the bound property is set to OneWay then the control works correctly but I am unable to detect the Swipe Event.

If the bound property is set to TwoWay I am able to detect the Swipe Event but the control does not function correctly.  For some reason I have to swipe the control twice for the property to be called.

Does anyone know why the control isn't working correctly and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425853/xamarin-forms-carousel-page-swipe-event-page-changing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for the link Chris, but this doesn't seem to be what I need.

The examples seem to be done in the Code-Behind instead of the ViewModel so I can't do a lot of what is shown there.

My main issue though is why is my binding working on every other swipe when set to TwoWay but when set to OneWay it works.  This seems to be the main problem and if this is fixed then I should be good...

Comment: @plingingo pardon me if this is not relevant. I am trying to hide the scrollbar when i swipe the carousel's manually. (horizontal scroll). Is there a way i could disable it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem appeared to be a bug in the control rather than something wrong with my code.

Upgrading the NuGet package to the latest version of the controls I was using fixed my issue.